# Any way to troubleshoot this mono native code crash further?

Tags: c#, mono, monodevelop

I have code like the below, which is regularly SIGSEV-ing in Mono runtime native code:

```
XDocument doc = myHelperFunction(...);
if(doc == null)return;
var reportBlocks = doc.Descendants ("ReportBlocks");
if(reportBlocks.Count() == 0){
  //log it
  return;
  }
int batchSize = (int)reportBlocks.Attributes("numCols").First();
```

The message I am getting is:

```
Native stacktrace:

    /usr/bin/mono() [0x4b73d8]
    /usr/bin/mono() [0x5073d8]
    /usr/bin/mono() [0x4273d8]
    /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpthread.so.0(+0x10340) [0x7fb8b876b340]
    /usr/bin/mono() [0x5073d8]
    /usr/bin/mono() [0x4273d8]
    /usr/bin/mono() [0x5073d8]
    /usr/bin/mono() [0x4273d8]
    /usr/bin/mono() [0x5073d8]
    /usr/bin/mono() [0x4273d8]
    /usr/bin/mono() [0x5073d8]
    /usr/bin/mono() [0x4273d8]
    /usr/bin/mono() [0x5073d8]
    [0x41f1a660]

Debug info from gdb:

Could not attach to process. ...

=================================
Got a SIGSEGV while exexuting native code. This usually indicates
a fatal error in the mono runtime or one of the native libraries
used by your application.
=================================
```

(That has had to be hand-copied, so the 0xNNN numbers are not all exact.)

I have breakpoints on all the above lines. It is fairly reliably crashing when processing the `reportBlocks.Count()` part. Sometimes it goes through it fine, then triggers on the second data query.

This is all from inside MonoDevelop. If I run with ctrl-F5, instead of F5, it never hits problems. If I remove all the breakpoints and use F5 it also never hits problems.

If I set a few consecutive breakpoints a bit further down the above function, I can also get it to happen.

So I don't think it is a specific LINQ call, or anything like that. On the other hand the stack trace is always the same.

This smells like a potential timing issue (i.e. another thread keeps running while one thread is getting paused in the debugger), especially as pthreads is the only useful information in the stack trace. But I cannot spot anything, and I am out of ideas for tracking it down further.

I'd hate to spend more time on this if it is just a mono runtime bug that only happens when setting breakpoints!

---

Versions:

> === MonoDevelop ===
>
> Version 4.0.12
>   Runtime:  Mono 3.2.8 (Debian 3.2.8+dfsg-4ubuntu1) (64-bit)    GTK
>   2.24.23   GTK# (2.12.0.0)
>
> === Build Information ===
>
> Git revision: Build date: 2014-01-08 14:59:33+0000

And using Linux, Mint 17.

System.Xml and System.Xml.Linq are both version 4.0.0.0 (though it may be coincidence that I seem to notice it when setting breakpoints on linq calls).

Comment: managed code without unsafe blocks shouldn't ever cause an unmanaged crash, so this is definitely a mono bug; what version of mono are you using?

Comment: Thanks @knocte, I've added version info. Mono 3.2.8, and MonoDevelop 4.0.12.

Comment: please test with Mono 3.10 and if you still experience the same problem, report a bug in http://bugzilla.xamarin.com/ attaching a minimal testcase that causes the crash

Comment: oh, and you should especially upgrade MonoDevelop, because v4.0.12 is very old